# Subviews are nil when UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCell are in XIB files

Tags: swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, xib

**[Hi there! I've created a sample project that shows my problem exactly. Click to download!](https://www.dropbox.com/s/78zkazkta4udzx5/CollectionViewProblem.zip?dl=1)**

I've created an app which contains a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`, it contains an `ImageView` as subview. It also has a XIB file containing the view.

When I use this `UICollectionViewCell` within a `UICollectionView` that is directly embedded in a `ViewController`, the cell works just fine. Here's the code of the **WorkingViewController** containing the code that registers the cell:

```
class WorkingViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
  @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "ImageCell", bundle: nil)
    collectionView.register(cellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell")

    collectionView.reloadData()
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  func randomInt(min: Int, max: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1))) + min
  }

  func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as? ImageCell else {
      fatalError("Could not load cell")
    }

    let randomNumber = randomInt(min: 1, max: 10)
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "stockphoto\(randomNumber)")

    return cell
  }
}
```

Now move the *Storyboard Entry Point* over to the **BuggyViewController**. Here the `UICollectionView` is not directly embedded. It is contained within a `UIView` that also has an `XIB`. Here's the code for that view, containing the registering of the cell from earlier:

```
class DetailView: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
  @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setup()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    setup()
  }

  private func setup() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DetailView", owner: self, options: nil)

    self.addSubview(self.contentView)
    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds
    self.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "ImageCell", bundle: nil)
    collectionView.register(cellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell")
    collectionView.register(ImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell")

    collectionView.reloadData()
  }

  func randomInt(min: Int, max: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1))) + min
  }

  func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as? ImageCell else {
      fatalError("Could not load cell")
    }

    let randomNumber = randomInt(min: 1, max: 10)
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "stockphoto\(randomNumber)")

    return cell
  }
}
```

But this results in an error in the DetailView, line 55:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

So here the `imageView` of the cell is suddenly nil which makes me think I did something wrong registering the cell or instantiating it. But I just cannot resolve it.

Comment: Could you delete this line 'collectionView.register(ImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell")' and see if you still get the same error? I think you are registering one too many times.

Comment: @Ocunidee that solves the problem and it works as it should... but I swear to god I've tried uncommenting those lines a million times before... I don't get it, but it works now! If you add an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should delete the line where you register the cell class:

```
collectionView.register(ImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell")
```

Indeed you've defined your cell in a Nib and should register it through the method `func register(_ nib: UINib?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String)`. Registering it through the cellClass method will return nil.

And as the Apple doc states:

> If you previously registered a class or nib file with the same reuse
>   identifier, the class you specify in the cellClass parameter replaces
>   the old entry. You may specify nil for cellClass if you want to
>   unregister the class from the specified reuse identifier.

This explains why you were getting nil.